# Maximum amount of TX per block

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, gas-limit

Yesterday we did a test. We launched around 1500 transactions simultaneously to our test private blockchain.

They all went through perfectly, all at almost the same time (with correct and consecutive nonces, from 5 different addresses).

In the genesis file, our private network is configured with these parameters:

```
"gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x400",
"maximumExtraDataSize": "0xF4240",
"minGasLimit": "0x1388",
"difficulty": "0x20000",
"gasLimit": "0x5B8D80"
```

And the estimated gas for each transaction was around 44500 wei.

According to my calculations, with this gasLimit and this cost, around 130 transactions could fit per block, but the amount that actually filled the block capped at 16.

Our nodes are 2 cores with 8GB of RAM.

Are our calculations wrong? why so few tx fitted into a block?

Thanks!

Comment: What was the gas limit of each of the transactions? You say the transactions were 44500 wei, but that is the gas * gasPrice. It's also possible that the sealing node just saw a number of transactions and, since I'm assuming this was PoA, it just created a block before it saw the rest.

Comment: Gas Price is always set to 0x0. You are correct that we are using PoA.

Comment: "And the estimated gas for each transaction was around 44500 wei." This says otherwise. What is the gas limit you're using for the transactions?

Comment: eth.estimateGas(tx) gives the 44500 wei value.
eth.getGasPrice() gives 0.

As far as I know, I'm not setting any gas limit for the transactions. Is there a default somewhere?